# How can I export my saved places data from Google Maps from my phone without using Google Takeout, and without connecting to the internet?

Tags: android, google-maps

My Google data was recently wiped by my organization, and while I was able to retrieve most of the data that I needed before the wipe, I was unable to retrieve my Google Maps data such as saved places, etc.

I found an old Android phone of mine which had not been connected to the internet during the wipe, and thus still retains much of my Google Maps data locally on the device itself. If I were to connect the phone to the internet, I would lose the local data.

How can I export my saved places data from Google Maps from my phone without using Google Takeout, and without connecting the phone to the internet?

My research shows that there should be a "Map.db" or "Maps.db" file in a folder named "com.google.android.apps.maps" or "com.google.android.apps.maps:maps".

I searched through my phone, but no such .db file seems to exist. Some users have reported finding a file called "local.db" in the Google Maps folder, which contains the saved places data, but I could not find this file either.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this code related?